# Can I connect to a specific workspace via VNC?

Tags: workspaces, vnc

I am running XBMC on my Ubuntu. But from time to time, I have to VNC into my system to do some maintenance. I then have to minimize my XBMC first.

Can I connect to another workspace instead?

Somewhere I read that I can connect to port 5901, 5902 and so on. But it does not work. I do not wish to install any other VNC server as I want to keep a lean setup, but I am open to options.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Have you read here? http://superuser.com/questions/32455/virtual-vnc-screen-workspace

Comment: This method just shows a small command line window.

Comment: This is very handy question, I'd like to bind VNC server (i.e. x11vnc) to the specific workspace (#2) and while working on workspace #1 I'll be able to watch debug windows from workspace #2 on the VNC client machine. This can't be solved by sessions because all applications will originate from one session.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use X11 forwarding over SSH. This will let you run both commandline and GUI tools.

To do this on Linux or OSX run: ssh user@host -X

Then run whatever you need from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to connect to another workspace on the current session. However, is is possible to have multiple sessions.

You could setup x11vnc + xinetd to achive your goal. The setup is not non-trivial, but there is a nice FAQ section at http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-userlogin

The link jasmines provided seems to be a solution as well.

Comment: Jasmines link works but it only enables a command line window.